# Screen Flow / LWC Quick Action Called Again on clicking browser back button

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We have screen flows / LWC Quick Qctions in our Project.  If i run the quick action and then click on browser back button then Quick Action is Called Again. Can someone please help me here. Thanks in Advance.

the quick action should not be called again on clicking browser back button.